# getElementByID("") with online src iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this code working fine with local file:

```
<html> 
<body>
<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" frameborder=0 src="form.html" width=100% height=70%></iframe>
</body> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload= function(){
        var iframe = document.getElementById('frame1');
        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var input = innerDoc.getElementsByName('input1')[0].value;
        alert(input);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

form.html:

```
<input name="input1" type="text" value="testing"/>
```

Everything ok, but when I change iframe's src:

```
<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" frameborder=0 src="form.html" width=100% height=70%></iframe>
```

With:

```
<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" frameborder=0 src="http://test.hklearningmap.com/form.html" width=100% height=70%></iframe>
```

It not working. How can I make it work without uploading local file to the same location with form.html? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that browsers impose. JavaScript code running in a window from Origin A cannot access the document in a window (frame) from Origin B.

There are some exceptions, such as when both documents assign the same value to [`document.domain`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/origin-0.html#dom-document-domain). But there are restrictions on the values that can be set (loosely, you can only set a superdomain, e.g. you can set `example.com` from a page loaded from `www.example.com`), and of course both documents have to set it (because that cooperation is what tells the browser it's okay to allow cross-origin scripting).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access remote html content with js just because you load it in iframe. Read about same origin policy.